# 2 classes, constructor and main not in the same class

Tags: java, class, user-interface, constructor

I have 2 classes in the class `Grafics`. I would like to put all the `grafic` stuff, like create frame, buttons, etc., in the `inhalt` class. I would like to create all the functions with the `grafics`.

my question:

is it possible to have the `Main` in the `inhalt` class and the constructor in the `grafics` class?

```
package uebung2;   
import javax.swing.JFrame;    
public class Grafics extends JFrame {       
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    public Grafics(){           
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
    }       
}
```

Class with the main method:

```
package uebung2;    
public class Inhalt {       
    public void main(String[]args){         
        Grafics fenster = new Grafics();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: why don't you try it yourself and post it if you have any difficulties or errors

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is - main is just the program entry point and it is generally preferable not to mix application glueing (like starting the program, setting up the environment) and the "business logic" of the program.